# SSRS How to show or hide certain rows based on a value

Tags: reporting-services

Working in SSRS 2012, I have a basic table listing a number of items with a sales quantity. I am trying to toggle the table to filter out rows where the sales quantity is zero, or include them.

In the Row Visibility I have entered the following expression:

`=iif(Fields!SalesQuantity.Value=0, True, False)`

and set the "Display can be toggled by this report item:" to a textbox.
The filter works fine and hides the items with zero sales, but when I toggle it the table only shows the items with zero sales and excludes the items with sales. Is it possible to show or hide the rows zero sales and always show the items with sales?

I realise I could do this at query level using a parameter, but I would prefer to toggle a filter so that the report would not need to be re-run.

Comment: =iif(Fields!SalesQuantity.Value=0, True,iif(Fields!SalesQuantity.Value !=0,FALSE,FALSE)) Something like this. When you toggle it looks like you are also saying everything that's not 0 be hidden.

Comment: @Snowlockk Thanks for your suggestion but I'm still getting the same results.